# Copy to android system clipboard in nvim from termux

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard

I use Neovim on termux on android 11
I commonly use `:y` to yank/copy text to nvim clipboard

Then paste it to another files

Recently I've tried using [helix-editor](https://helix-editor.com)(hx) looks and feels so similar to Neovim (with NVChad/spacevim) with a bunch of themes

In its normal mode there is a command `:clipboard-yank`
which literally **Yank main selection into system clipboard.** after selection of required text.

and similar function is also available on tmux too..

but in nvim it doesn't copy to system clipboard

I tried searching for this function and fond some solutions but those didnt worked for me

```lua
set clipboard=unnamed
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set clipboard+=unnamed
```

or these `"*y` `"+y`

in command mod I tried this command `echo has('clipboard')` it returned `0`  instead of a clipboard name

so, is there any way to copy to system clipboard

Comment: I'm not sure [Helix](https://helix-editor.com/) is considered as vi compatible which is the criteria for this forum (see: (What is considered vi?)[https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/37/23502])

Comment: don't you need to setup a clipboard provider?

Comment: Did you try `set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus`?

Comment: @Tae yup I did tried it